# Fonction rejouer en c#

Tags: c#

I am learning about C # programming and I stumble on a part of my code. I use visual studio 2017.

I develop a mystery number game and I would like to make sure to replay but I do not know how to do it.

I would like that when we press O or N it plays again or else it quits, but I can not. Scanf and printf do not work. Thank you for your next answer.

```
char play;
bool isvalid = true;

void Number() 
{
    //Code...
    While(isvalid); 
    {
         Console.WriteLine("want to play again o/n "); 
         if(play == 'o') 
         {
              Number();
          }
          else 
          {
               play == 'n';
          }
    }
}

Number();
```

Comment: You're not accepting any input after prompting the user to change the state of `play`; that would be the first step.

Comment: "_Fonction rejouer en c#_" Huh?

Comment: Spend some time with the documentation for the [`Console`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console?view=netframework-4.7.1) class (or pretty much any C# tutorial/guide covering console input and output; learning programming is as much about reading -- if not more -- as it is about writing code). It not only has methods/functions to output stuff through the console, but it has also (unsurprisingly) methods to read stuff the user inputs through the console...

Answer (score 0):

I see couple of issues in the pasted code:

- First of all, you there is a semicolon after the while loop.  Because of it, the lines in the curly brackets are not getting executed again and again as you expect them to.
- Second - you are not populating `play` variable.  You should use **Console.Readline** (you can enter any string and then hit enter to come out of input prompt) OR **Console.Read** (to read just 1 char)
- Third - You are calling Number function again and again - if you play your game for sufficiently long time it would cause stack overflow exception.

What I understood from your code is you want to execute some code again and again if user keeps on entering 'o' character.  Otherwise you want to stop that loop.

The code would be :

```
void Number() 
{
    //Code...

    While(isvalid); 
    {
         Console.WriteLine("want to play again o/n "); 
         play = Console.Read();

          if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(play) && play.Equals('o', CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) 
          {
              /////// Some code you want to execute;
          }
          else 
          {
               ////// Some code you want to execute if user enters anything other than 'o'.

                ////// If you want to stop loop, set isValid = false; OR use break statement
          }
    }
}
```

I know that this answer may not solve your problem completely.
Hope this helps you to understand what code you should write.